# Erro ao inserir dados no MySQL - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho o código

```
<?php
$chave = $retorno->resposta->cobrancasGeradas->cliente->cobranca->chave;

$this->db->insert('boletos', array('id_fatura'=>$id_fatura, 'chave_boleto'=>$chave));
?>
```

Quando ele executa esse `insert` me retorna o erro:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'HILO3' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `boletos` (`id_fatura`, `chave_boleto`) VALUES (20, 81954-30765231-HILO3)

Filename: /var/www/html/Cotas/models/conta_model.php

Line Number: 168
```

O tipo de campo do `chave_boleto` no MySQL é `varchar(100)`

Comment: Esse valor `81954-30765231-HILO3`está indo sem as aspas e por isso não é um varchar, Não entendi bem como isso funciona (`'chave_boleto'=>$chave`), mas tem que fazer isso retornar as aspas. Vamos esperar alguém explicando como é.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é basicamente na query, parece que ele está tentando inserir o valor de uma string, como número, e dá erro, experimente fazer um cast no tipo:

```
<?php
$chave = $retorno->resposta->cobrancasGeradas->cliente->cobranca->chave;

$this->db->insert('boletos', array('id_fatura' => $id_fatura, 'chave_boleto' => (string) $chave));
?>
```

ou isso:

```
 $this->db->insert('boletos', array('id_fatura' => $id_fatura, 'chave_boleto' => "{$chave}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php
     $chave = $retorno->resposta->cobrancasGeradas->cliente->cobranca->chave;
     $dados['id_fatura'] = $id_fatura;
     $dados['chave_boleto'] = $chave;
     $this->db->insert('boletos', $dados);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

só adaptar ao seu modo.

Maneira correta com PDO.
O bom seria voce fazer uma classe abstrata com os CRUD (abstract class Crud extends DB ) colocar esse código e substituir os valores por variáveis, depois só chamar o crud em sua classe que deseja fazer o insert.

mas no grosso está ai.

```
    try {
            DB::getInstance()->beginTransaction();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO boletos (id_fatura,chave_boleto) VALUES (:id_fatura, :chave_boleto)";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
            $dados = seuArray //array('id_fatura'=>$id_fatura, 'chave_boleto'=>$chave)

            foreach ($dados as $key => $v) {
                $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $v);
            }
            //ou assim
            //$stmt->bindValue(':id_fatura', 1);
            //$stmt->bindValue(':chave_boleto', 'fjçalkdfjoajlaksdf');


            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $cd = DB::getInstance()->lastInsertId();
                modalSalvo("Salvo com sucesso!");
                return $cd;
                DB::getInstance()->commit();
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<br />Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```